# Interpreting IEPY documentation commands

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I have some troubles in interpreting the documentation (http://iepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) commands of IEPY package for Natural Language Processing. The first step to work with IEPY is to create an "instance" (as a non-programmer I have little idea what is it all about). They also provide the command to do it:

```
iepy --create <project_name>
```

My problem is that when I type the exact sentence into my command line, I get a syntax error. I suppose that I do not follow some coding conventions and misinterpret what I should really type. Would be glad to hear what I do wrong.

Comment: Though this question is quite off-topic from data science as is, it would be easy to speculate/answer, if you can provide the exact error produced.

Comment: Unfortunately, the command simply reports me a "syntax error" and nothing else. P.s. I think you're right on "off-topic" and it makes more sense to post it on stackoverflow instead, which did not notice at first.